# Modeling of an application. When to use which diagram?

Tags: c++, modeling, uml

My project meanwhile got bigger and bigger. Now an then I find myself lost in my code and even changing things that had fixed in the concept in my mind. This is horrible because as my lines of code grow my productivity shrinks. I just want to achieve that my productivity remains constant. Now I want to get my application on paper to get the overview back, if im lost again, and to have something that I can stick to. But I dont know how to model correctly. I tried to model it complete in a state chart but that, for example, is not applicable if the code just executes things that do not have a state line by line. In this case a flowchart would be fine. But I dont know how mix it, so that it makes sense overall.

How should I start getting things on paper? What is common practice to model a bigger application? When do I use which diagram?

Comment: It sounds like you've just written a lot of spaghetti code. Throw it out and start over.

Comment: You might be a [Cowboy coder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cowboy_coding), and now the lack of design is coming back to haunt you.

Comment: You use whichever diagram serves the purpose. UML is a tool, not a process. (Although it's frequently misunderstood as such.) Ask yourself, "what do I need written down?", then use the diagram type that covers this best.

Comment: Its not that bad. I really tried to keep it clean. But somehow its large and I am forgetful. Sometimes I dont think of some dependencies, write code for a few hours and realise that I coded crap the last hours. UML is neither a tool nor a process. Its a modeling language. Actually I am familar to UML due to lectures about software engineering but I never had practise on it. I know well what it is but fewer how to use it correctly. Apart from that its not all about the code I already have witten. Its about something I can stick to, so I can write according to it.

Answer (score 2):

To understand the flow of the program you could use Activity Diagrams. To understand interaction between objects you could use sequence diagrams. To understand the modules, you could use class diagrams and perhaps bring related classes inside a package. You can then draw high level dependencies between the modules. That will give you a high level as well as bit detailed level information about your project.

Comment: Okay these are things to model parts of it. But how would you illustrate somebody how the application works *overall*?

Comment: You might use the architectural view or high level design to show how system components will be communicating with each other. And then if needed, go onto describing individual component in detail.

Answer (score 0):

As an answer to the comment "But how would you illustrate somebody how the application works overall?": for a big application, you can't.  How does MsWord work overall?

To show how parts in the application work, you use [use-cases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use_case).  From there on, you use [class diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram) (structure), [sequence diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_diagram) (program flow) and [state diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_diagram_%28UML%29) (state) as appropriate to show the design per use case.  Your code should reflect these diagrams

Answer (score 0):

Model driven development allows you to bring quality assurance for your software. First of all, no matter how costly or time-consuming it is, it should be done for all projects especially when the scale of project grows up. I have the same issue with our own project which has been developed first without any models. So be patient.

First step in realizing the system to implement, is to describe what the system should do, what is observable, how is the interaction with users and other systems. Use Case Diagram is your way to answer these questions.

Then you may think about how many classes you might need. In your case, since you have coded some part already, thinking of how to decouple the main functionality into many small classes and to establish the relation between them. There you need Class Diagram.

These two are most common notations you must have at least to have an overview of your overall structure.

If you have many classes now, then how does the system behave? How is the order or sequence of data and work flow? In your most important scenario what kind of calls in which sequence should be executed to make a task done? That's why you need Sequence Diagram or collaboration diagram.

I would say start with these and continue with [more models](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/31863) afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

To untangle a large mess, I would start by deciding what the different subject matters of the application are.  For example, in a driverless car, you might have image processing, foreign body detection and avoidance, road acquisition and tracking, speed regulation, navigation, etc.  If you are mixing your topics in the same module, you are in trouble.  Each one of these subject matters can be a namespace.  Then, divide your classes/modules into their proper namespaces.  Figure out how various use cases can be handled by your classes and add/delete classes as necessary.  Then follow rules of the book "Clean Code" and keep your methods simple.

The 4+1 View into an architecture indicates that there is no single view that describes the whole system.  4+1 discusses using logical, development, process, physical, and scenario views.  All of these have UML counterparts.